# Docusign .Net Client and Send on Behalf Of(SOBO)

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use Send on Behalf Of (SOBO) functionality of DocuSign. I read about it and I know there are two ways to do it. Using OAuth to obtain a access_token and then use with with X-DocuSign-Act-As-User or using SendOnBehalfOf element in X-DocuSign-Authentication.

I am also would like to use DocuSign .NET client. From reading the code I can see that first option is not supported (OAuth). So I went for X-DocuSign-Authentication which is supported thru Account.SOBOUserId property.

```
RestSettings.Instance.IntegratorKey = "***";
        RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress = "http://demo.docusign.net";
        RestSettings.Instance.WebServiceUrl = RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress + "/restapi/v2";
        RestSettings.Instance.RestTracing = true;

        // credentials for sending account
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Email = "a@yopmail.com";
        account.Password = "****";
        account.SOBOUserId = "b@yopmail.com";

        // make the Login API call
        bool result = account.Login();

        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();

        envelope.Login = account;  // assign account info from above

        envelope.Recipients = new Recipients()
        {
            signers = new Signer[] { new Signer() {
                    email = "****@hotmail.com",
                    name = "Test",
                    routingOrder = "1",
                    recipientId = "1"
                }}
        };

        // "sent" to send immediately, "created" to save envelope as draft
        envelope.Status = "sent";
        envelope.EmailSubject = "DocuSign Test document";
        // create a new DocuSign envelope (i.e. server side)
        result = envelope.Create(@"C:\temp\dummyPDF.pdf");
```

I did what is necessary to as a setup in DocuSign UI to allow sending of behalf of b@yopmail.com as shown in the documentation. However when i run this code the receiver received email from a@yopmail.com instead of b@yopmail.com. It seems as it SOBO is not working at all.

My Question is can I use SOBO functionality using DocuSign .Net Client?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your Account class? I would expect it to be `account.SendOnBehalfOf` and not `account.SOBOUserId`

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client/blob/master/DocuSign.Integrations.Client/Account.cs

Comment: It seems because of defect in DocuSign .NET Client this is not working. if you look at https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client/blob/master/DocuSign.Integrations.Client/RequestBuilder.cs

method SetLogonCredentials - you'll see SendOnBehalfOf element is not added to authorization header if AuthorizationFormat is Xml. I made a change to force it to Json and it is working now.

Comment: The code is an opensource SDK. I wonder if you can submit that change to it. But I agree that nothing ever happens with SOBOUserId after it's declared in regards to login

Answer (score 0):

It seems because of defect in DocuSign .NET Client this is not working. if you look at github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client/blob/master/… method SetLogonCredentials - you'll see SendOnBehalfOf element is not added to authorization header if AuthorizationFormat is Xml. I made a change to force it to Json and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

The `Envelope.Create(filepath)` method does not properly use the SOBOUserID field.   It just simply hasn't been added yet to the code due to other priorities.  I've added a pull request to fix this, but in the mean time you can either fix it the way I have or use the other `Envelope.Create()` methods that use `byte` arrays instead of the filepath.

See issue and resolution here:
https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-.NET-Client/issues/69